# Resize a group of objects based on an item in the group

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to take a sub-object of a group and resize it, then have the rest of the group follow along with the transformation?

To illustrate my problem:

I have these three groups on the first line of this image, all squares but with different things also included in the group. I'd like the groups resized so that the squares are all the same size (my best attempt at this on the second line, they're actually slightly different because I just dragged them by hand),[image]

Comment: The middle group is easy, just set the width to the same width as the left group ensuring the retain proportions chain icon is "linked". I can't seem to work out a technically accurate method for the right group.

Comment: Looks like no way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way, if you don't want to or can't align them as you already did is to find the scale of the squares and then rescale the items (grouped!) by that factor to achieve the same dimensions. I'm pretty sure is not possible to do exactly what you are asking in Illustrator

Comment: I guess good old maths is the solution here. Thanks all for confirming that there wasn't some function I had overlooked here, though.

Comment: no problem, you're welcome